# Can someone please help me simplify these echo statements?

Tags: php, echo

```
 echo $User->FirstName; 
 echo T(' '); 
 echo $User->Surname; 
 echo T(' '); 
 echo T('(');
 echo UserAnchor($User); 
 echo T(')');  
 echo T(' ');
 echo $User->Company;
```

I realise this is a big mess and surely not the way to do several echo statements. But it gives the layout I want.

Is there a better way of writing it?

Comment: build a string through concatenation then echo the result?

Comment: what does T() do exactly?

Comment: @PSR are you sure that edit is valid? if the lack-of-newline is one of the things the OP has in his code (maybe reason why it is a big mess) it should be represented in the question

Comment: Is it any any CMS or framweork ?

Comment: @Nanne sorry  for false edit.By mistake i did

Comment: It's using a great deal of the vanilla forums framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below with only one echo statement..

```
echo "$User->FirstName  $User->Surname (".UserAnchor($User).")  $User->Company";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the separate calls like this:

```
echo $User->FirstName . T(' ') . $User->Surname . T(' ') . T('(') . 
UserAnchor($User) . T(')') . T(' ') . $User->Company
```

You can only do this if `T` is a valid function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $User->FirstName. T(' '). $User->Surname T(' '). T('('). 
UserAnchor($User). T(')'). T(' '). $User->Company;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $User->FirstName.T(' ').$User->Surname; echo T(' ').T('(').UserAnchor($User).T(')'); echo T(' ').$User->Company;
```